# how to make g++ command work in VSCode with mingw

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-code

I am trying to set up Visual Studio Code to work with C++ and Mingw. I am using the tutorial https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw. When I use ctrl+shift+b to build helloworld.cpp as said in the tutorial, I get the error message:

```
> Executing task: g++ -g -o helloworld helloworld.cpp <

g++ : The term 'g++' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name
, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ g++ -g -o helloworld helloworld.cpp
+ ~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (g++:String) [], 
CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Where could the problem lie? Did I configure bash wrongly?

Comment: I assume you are on Windows. Have you followed the steps in section "Prerequisites"? Do you have Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) installed? If you type `g++ --version` in the terminal, what's the outcome?

Comment: Yes, I am on Windows. g++ : The term 'g++' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name
, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ g++ --version
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (g++:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: I don't have WSL installed. It looks like Powershell doesn't see g++

Comment: I didn't add g++ and bash paths to Windows system variable PATH, now it does see g++.

Comment: Now after ctrl+shift+b: > Executing task: g++ -g -o helloworld helloworld.cpp <
g++.exe: error: helloworld.cpp: No such file or directory

Comment: Where are you executing the last command? Have you *saved* the .cpp file?

Comment: The last command is executed automatically in VSCode terminal after pressing ctrl+shift+b - I'm following the instructions here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_build-the-program. Yes, I have saved it.